# Is it okay to drop DNS type AAAA queries

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables

If a DNSSEC server has no zones with AAAA records.  What potential problems could there be by dropping DNS type AAAA (28; 0x1c) queries at the firewall?

Same as dropping type ANY (255; 0xff).  Just replace the type with AAAA (28; 0x1c).

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What do you have specifically against `AAAA` records and why to filter those and not others? Why can't you the server reply NODATA or NXDOMAIN as needed? As for  `ANY` please read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8482 ; most of the time putting a firewall in front of a DNS server is a bad idea until at least you understand fully well how the DNS works.

Comment: Also, IPv6 should be the current Internet and IPv4 be legacy. Your nameserver should have IPv6 transport and you should have `AAAA` records as you should have all your resources available over IPv6. Why such desire to tie you to the past?

Answer (score 28):

All your clients would wait for a few seconds on every DNS lookup, for starters. IPv6 is not optional and modern operating systems treat it as such. A client looking for an address will look up both AAAA and A records, even if it does not seem to have any IPv6 connectivity at that exact moment. If you drop one of the queries, the client software doing the DNS lookup will wait until a timeout before returning an error. You will thus annoy your users with a needless slowdown.

Back around 2012, some Juniper firewalls did by accident what you propose to do on purpose, and would drop the AAAA response, even though the client specifically requested A and AAAA records. Juniper eventually did fix this, but it caused quite a bit of annoyance to anybody stuck with this malfunctioning equipment.

And of course it's 2020 and your entire network should have already been IPv6 for the last several years, with IPv4 dual stacked or even deprecated to legacy stuff. But some places are extraordinarily slow to join this century, and you're probably working at one...

Comment: What information is the last paragraph trying to add to this answer in regards to the question asked?

Comment: @NumLock: As the OP seems to think IPv6 isn't worth while to support, or should even be blocked actively, telling them they're wrong is very much in order.

Comment: @GuntramBlohmsupportsMonica Probably, I was more focused on the passive-aggressiveness towards implying OP being _extraordinarily slow to join this century_, though. I am sure it can be phrased more informative and less opinionated/insulting, if not even be left out completely. Like it was before the last edit.

Comment: @NumLock I expect it's his employer rather than him; it usually is. And I did say exactly that in so many words. Most people in IT are quite happy to have shiny new things, even when they're 20 year old shiny new things. And there's nothing passive about it. I've been watching people stumble around in the dark for years now with a wide variety of nasty hacks and workarounds, that they have no need to suffer through, because they are unable or unwilling to deploy IPv6. It's really well past time to move on.

Comment: The question was what problems could arise if you'd go and drop your AAAA DNS records. How does the last paragraph add any relevant information to an answer regarding that question? Why not just something along the lines of "_You should, however, really consider upgrading to IPv6 anyway, as IPv4 is considered legacy by most now._" instead of "_Hurr, it's 2020 dude, update to IPv6 stuff, but you are one of the slow plebs, aren't you?_".

Comment: @NumLock You've chosen to see an insult where none exists or was intended. That's all on you.

Comment: My ISP has been promising IPv6 "real soon now" for the last 10 years. And so does the other major ISP in this country. Not that I can switch ISP's anyway. My current one is the only one providing decent bandwidth (DocSis) in  my area. All the others are DSL which absolutely sucks if there is 5 miles of copper to deal with. Fiber? Maybe in 10 years or so.

Comment: @Tonny It's true, such is life in many parts of the world, even some developed countries. For instance BT in the UK said the same thing for many years and has only just gotten round to deploying IPv6 in the last couple of years. There's little you can do about it, and it's fine to not have global IPv6 if you just can't get it at all.

Comment: Seconded that in some parts of the world the issue is the ISPs, not the companies themselves. Most companies in such areas are willing to admit that if it were not such a hassle to get IPv6 support from their ISP, they would love to support it, but cannot justify the overhead of either doing it themselves or doing the often ridiculous things their ISP requires to get IPv6 support from them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The Netherlands isn’t exactly an underdeveloped country but getting IPv6... For businesses it is no problem  (provided you have a fiber uplink), but for consumers.... If the  ISPs allows it they force you in a half assed non-standard Ds-lite implementation and/or don’t allow dual-stack.

Comment: @J... IPv6 solves a very large number of problems, that it people are working around in different and more expensive ways today. I'm a little surprised people still believe this myth.

Comment: @Tonny I live in the Netherlands, and I have a consumer ISP that provides IPv6 since 2012. I get a full proper /48 network. What ISP's did you test for IPv6 support?

Comment: @Ferrybig Let me guess. Xs4All? I'm stuck with Ziggo. No fiber here and DSL variants give me 15 - 20 mb/s down at most (45 year old telephone cabling). At least Ziggo gives me 500/40, but no IPV6 in my region, unless I'm a business customer. And they refuse IPv6 when the Docsis modem is in bridge. (For me bridge is a must. The router part of their Docsis devices is underpowered and only allows basic configuration. Would you believe you can't disable UPnP?) I do have IPv6 via a tunnel provider. Less than ideal, but at least it works well enough that I can test my own software with IPv6.